# Kodaira dimension of co-adjoint orbit

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, lie-groups, sg.symplectic-geometry

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group and $a\in\mathfrak{g}^*$ (dual of Lie algebra of Lie group $G$). Then let $\mathcal O_a$ be a coadjoint orbit. Then every co-adjoint orbit is Kähler manifold and also projective variety. How can we compute the Kodaira dimension of co-adjoint orbit as projective variety?

> Motivation: The Kodaira dimension of co-adjoint orbits are important,
>   because we can classify these type of projective varieties by  Kodaira
>   dimension which is birationally invariant.

In fact I am looking for

$$\kappa(\mathcal O_a)=\limsup_{m\to \infty}\frac{\log\text{dim}H^0(\mathcal O_a, K_{\mathcal O_a}^{\otimes m})}{\log m}$$

Comment: In fact, coadjoint orbit is hyper-kahler variety, so normally the canonical bundle is trivial and Kodaira dimension must be 0. Am I wrong?

Comment: The coadjoint orbits are *not* hyperKähler varieties.  In fact, they are homogeneous and have positive Ricci curvature.

Comment: Thanks , I will edit my question. So, I think we must use of Kirillov's dimension formula and Borel–Weil theorem

Comment: Do you mean the projectivized coadjoint orbits? The coadjoint orbits are subvarieties of $\mathfrak{g}^*$, so not compact and so not projective. The orbits in $\mathbb{P}(\mathfrak{g}^*)$ are usually not called coadjoint orbits, I think.

Comment: $\mathcal O_a\cong G/G_a\cong G^{\mathbb C}/P$ and see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/156394/is-g-t-a-projective-variety

Comment: See Peter Crooks's answer in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/156394/is-g-t-a-projective-variety

Comment: Robert Bryant@, all coadjoint orbits of complex reductive groups admit hyperkähler structures. So, in non-compact reductive Lie Groups, your statement need to revision. This is know fact of Olivier Biquard

Comment: @Hassan: Your question is about ${\it compact}$ Lie groups, in which case coadjoint orbits are ${\it not}$ hyperkaehler - consider for example $S^2$, a coadjoint orbit for $su(2)$. There is no need for Robert Bryant to revise his statement. The coadjoint orbits of a complex simple Lie algebra are another thing.

Comment: Peter Dalakov@ Yes, You right, thanks

Comment: By the Bruhat decomposition they are rational varieties, so your motivation is not particularly motivating.

Comment: Allen Knutson@ Can you explain more, please, thanks for your nice comment.

Comment: $G/P$ is birationally equivalent to its open Bruhat cell, a vector space. So birational invariants of $G/P$s are boring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your manifold $X$ has positive Ricci curvature, the line bundles $K_X^m$ are all ${ negative}$ for $m\geq 1$, i.e. they admit a smooth Hermitian metric with negative curvature. By Kodaira Vanishing, we conclude that $H^0(X,K_X^m)=0$ for all $m\geq 1$, i.e. the Kodaira dimension is $-\infty$.

Comment: Thanks YangMils@, you could you of also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Weil%E2%80%93Bott_theorem ,

Comment: Indeed, $K_X = -2\rho$ so not dominant, under the usual indexing of line bundles by weights.

Comment: Allen Knutson@, I need more detail, to undrestand

Comment: A $G$-equivariant line bundle $\mathcal L$ on $G/B$ is uniquely determined by the $T$-weight on the line $\mathcal L|_{w_0 B/B}$ over the top point $w_0 B/B \in G/B$; if it's $\lambda$ (and dominant) then the space of sections is the irrep with high weight $\lambda$. Now, the tangent space $T_{B/B} G/B$ at the basepoint is $\mathfrak g/\mathfrak b$, with weights $\Delta_-$. Add those up and you get $-2\rho$. Now dualize (because we want the cotangent space, for $K_X$) and hit with $w_0$, obtaining $-2\rho$ again. In particular, when you add up all the negative roots, the result isn't dominant.

Comment: Ohhh, thanks a lot, Now I undrestand that why Hirzebruch said that the first chern class of flag variaty is $2ρ$