# Geodesics on Homogeneous Spaces of $SU(n)$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, lie-algebras

Consider the homogeneous space $SU(n)/K$, where $K$ is a sub-group of $SU(n)$ and the bi-invariant metric on $SU(n)$.

What is the appropriate quotient metric on the homogeneous space and what are the geodesics? Clearly, for example, $K=U(n-1)$ gives $\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$ and the Fubini-Study geodesics which can be expressed in terms of the original geodesics on $SU(n)$. Is any similar formula available for the more general case and is the resulting metric unique (upto constant positive multiple) as in the FS case?

I'm not seeking homogeneous geodesics specifically.

Comment: In the case when $K$ is maximal torus $T$ or Borel group, then we have such homogeneous spaces as coadjoint orbits ,  see https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0602016

Comment: Kirillov-Kostant-Souriau metric, when $K$ is maximal torus $T$ or Borel group, note that such metrics on coadjoint orbits are K\"ahler and complex coadjoint orbit is projective in general. see pages 150, 151 for more precise information, http://www.emis.de/proceedings/Varna/vol9/Bernatska.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the answers to your and related questions are covered in Ch.X of

[1] Foundations of Differential Geometry, vol. II, Kobayashi, Nomizu

More specifically, let $\mathfrak g:=Lie(SU(n))$ and $\mathfrak k:=Lie(K)$ be Lie algebras of the corresponding groups. Since $SU(n)$ is a compact simple Lie group there is unique (up to multiple) invariant metric $\kappa$ on $\mathfrak g$ coming from the Killing form.

Let us fix a point $p=[eK]\in M=SU(n)/K$; any invariant tensor on $M$ is completely determined by its value at $p$. In particular, invariant metric on $M$ is determined by a metric on $T_p M\simeq \mathfrak g/\mathfrak k$, where isomorphism is given by the infinitesimal action along $X\in\mathfrak g$. One of the ways to equip $\mathfrak g/\mathfrak k$ with a metric is to identify it with a $\kappa$-orthogonal complement of $\mathfrak k$. This way you get so-called **naturally reductive** homogeneous space. For $K=SU(n-1)$ this gives Fubini-Study metric on $\mathbb P(n-1)$; for $K=S(U(k)\times U(n-k))$ this metric makes $Gr(n,k)$ a symmetric space.

There are two important connections on $M$ with a naturally reductive metric. One is the standard Levi-Civita connection $\nabla^{LC}$ corresponding to the metric defined above, another one is **canonical** connection $\nabla$ (see Ch X.2 of [1]). Important facts are:

1. $\nabla^{LC}$ and $\nabla$ have the same geodesics (Theorem 2.10 and Theorem 3.3 in [1])
2. Geodesic of $\nabla$ in the direction $X\in \mathfrak k^\perp\simeq T_p M$ is given by the curve $\exp (tX)p$ (Corollary 2.5 in [1]).
3. Any invariant tensor field on $M$ is $\nabla$-parallel.

Finally, I would like to mention that naturally reductive metric is not the only invariant metric on $M$ and other invariant metrics might have different geodesics.

Comment: in your last sentence, you probably mean left-invariant? the bi-invariant one is unique up to scalar multiplication. "invariant" means both left or bi-invariant according to authors.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I got your point. I am talking about invariant metrics on homogeneous spaces, and they admit only left group action, unless it is some very special case, like $M=SU(n)$

Comment: OK I thought you referred to the reductive metric on $SU(n)$. Indeed there's no ambiguity on $SU(n)/K$ (if one still refers to the reductive metric).

Comment: Is there an expression for the metric?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by expression. If you have fixed identification $\mathfrak k^\perp\simeq T_pM$, then the naturally reductive metric is given the restriction of the Killing metric, which for SU(n) is just the Frobenius norm.

Comment: If your $M$ is a coadjoint orbit as in Hassan's comment, then $M$ is a submanifold of $\mathfrak g^*$ and naturally reductive metric is given by restricting the metric $\kappa$ from $\mathfrak g^*$.

Comment: Note that, I said complex coadjoint orbit, .ie $G^{\mathbb C}/P$, which is projective variety

Comment: there is a difference between real coadjoint orbit, and complex coadjoint orbit. real coadjoint orbit is affine, but complex coadjoint orbit is projective . see my old question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/156394/is-g-t-a-projective-variety

Comment: A note about @YuryUstinovskiy's comment: the K\"ahler metric on a coadjoint orbit of a compact group is not the metric restricted from $\mathfrak g^*$. Indeed, for $SU(2)$ where the coadjoint orbits are concentric $2$-spheres, the K\"ahler area of an orbit is proportional to its radius, not the square of its radius.

Comment: Allen was right, see corollary page 5, https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/F16996C843F07E0EE63C081CCB7F5C63/S0004972700016300a.pdf/div-class-title-invariant-kahler-metrics-and-projective-embeddings-of-the-flag-manifold-div.pdf